# How can I use the "gets" function many times in my C program?

Tags: c, memory, runtime-error, runtime, gets

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        char a[10],b[10];
        puts("enter");
        gets(a);
        puts("enter");
        gets(b);
        puts("enter");
        puts(a);
        puts(b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1

enter 

enter

surya  (string entered by user)

enter

surya   (last puts function worked)
```

Comment: [The number of times you should use `gets()` in any program is zero.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/1679849)

Comment: @r3mainer That comment should be *the* answer to that question.

Comment: While I do agree with @r3mainer's comment, I would also suggest reading some book on the C language. ( K&R is best, [Beej' guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/html/single/bgc.html) is available for free. ) In particular, it won't hurt to get some understanding of strings and variables. In your case, `gets()` faithfully reads anything until user hits <Enter>, and then `puts()`, well, writes that. ( All this putting aside possible issues with overflows, etc -- read e.g. any modern man page on `gets()` . )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I use “gets” function many times in C program?

You should **never ever** use `gets()` in your program. It is deprecated because it is dangerous for causing buffer overflow as it has no possibility to stop consuming at a specific amount of characters - f.e. and mainly important - the amount of characters the buffer, `a` or `b` with each 10 characters, is capable to hold.

Also explained here:

[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Specially, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309845/12139179) answer from Jonathan Leffler.

Use `fgets()` instead.

---

Also the defintion of `a` and `b` inside of the `while` loop doesn´t make any sense, even tough this is just a toy program and for learning purposes.

Furthermore note, that `scanf()` leaves the newline character, made by the press to return from the `scanf()` call in `stdin`. You have to catch this one, else the first `fgets()` thereafter will consume this character.

---

Here is the corrected program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    char a[10],b[10];

    if(scanf("%d",&t) != 1)
    {
        printf("Error at scanning!");
        return 1;
    }

    getchar();          // For catching the left newline from scanf().

    while(t--)
    {        
        puts("Enter string A: ");
        fgets(a,sizeof a, stdin);
        puts("Enter string B: ");
        fgets(b,sizeof b, stdin);

        printf("\n");

        puts(a);
        puts(b);

        printf("\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
$PATH/a.out
2
Enter string A:
hello
Enter string B:
world

hello

world


Enter string A:
apple
Enter string B:
banana

apple

banana
```

Answer (score 3):

The most important message for you is:

**Never use `gets`** - it can't protect against buffer overflow. Your buffer can hold 9 characters and the termination character but `gets` will allow the user to typing in more characters and thereby overwrite other parts of the programs memory. Attackers can utilize that. So no `gets` in any program.

Use `fgets` instead!

That said - what goes wrong for you?

The `scanf` leaves a newline (aka a `'\n'`) in the input stream. So the first `gets` simply reads an empty string. And the second `gets` then reads "surya".

Test it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        char a[10],b[10];
        puts("enter");
        gets(a);        // !!! Use fgets instead
        puts("enter");
        gets(b);        // !!! Use fgets instead
        puts("enter");
        printf("|%s| %zu", a, strlen(a));
        printf("|%s| %zu", b, strlen(b));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1
surya
whatever
```

Output:

```
enter
enter
enter
|| 0|surya| 5
```

So here you see that `a` is just an empty string (length zero) and that `b` contains the word "surya" (length 5).

If you use `fgets` you can protect yourself against user-initiated buffer overflow - and that is important.

But `fgets` will **not** remove the `'\n'` left over from the `scanf`. You'll still have to get rid of that your self.

For that I recommend dropping `scanf` as well. Use `fgets` followed by `sscanf`. Like:

```
if (fgets(a,sizeof a, stdin) == NULL)
{
    // Error
    exit(1);
}
if (sscanf(a, "%d", &t) != 1)
{
    // Error
    exit(1);
}
```

So the above code will automatically remove `'\n'` from the input stream when inputtin `t` and the subsequent `fgets` will start with the next word.

Putting it all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    char a[10],b[10];
    if (fgets(a,sizeof a, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        // Error
        exit(1);
    }
    if (sscanf(a, "%d", &t) != 1)
    {
        // Error
        exit(1);
    }

    while(t--)
    {
        puts("enter");
        if (fgets(a,sizeof a, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            // Error
            exit(1);
        }
        puts("enter");
        if (fgets(b,sizeof b, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            // Error
            exit(1);
        }
        puts("enter");
        printf("%s", a);
        printf("%s", b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1
surya 
whatever
```

Output:

```
enter
enter
enter
surya 
whatever
```

Final note:

`fgets` will - unlike `gets` - also save the `'\n'` into the destination buffer. Depending on what you want to do, you may have to remove that `'\n'` from the buffer.